# Get rid Of Many Events and Properties in user control windows appilication

Tags: c#, user-controls, c#-4.0

Hi Experts
I create an user control in windows application.

when it inherits from Control base class it would have many events and properties that may be not uses in usercontrol and I what to hide then in Properties Window.

How I can do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following 3 attributes on the events or properties:
when you cannot override the property, just replace 'override' with 'new'. The EditorBrowsable attribute has no effect on the properties window, but on the code editor.

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get 
        {
            //implementattion
        }
        set 
        {
            //implementation
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood properly, then you should change the accessor level base control methods and events to private which you want to hide from child class.